# Handlebars Select List

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying list my data to select's options.I'm using handlebars backbone jquery requireJS.

This is my template

```
    <select id="userSelect">
<option value="" selected="selected">Kullanıcı Seçiniz</option>
{{#each users}}
<option value='{{userID}}'>{{username}}</option>
{{/users}}
</select>
```

My View

```
var users = new User();
var SelectUserList = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: User,
    el:'.page',
    render:function(users)
    {
        var template = Handlebars.compile(SelectUserList);
        var html = template({users:users.toJSON()});
        $("#userSelect").html(html);
        this.$el.html(SelectUserList);
        return this;

    }
});

return {
    users:users,
    SelectUserList:SelectUserList
};
```

And my Router.js

```
  user: function () {
        var spinner = new Spinner();
        $('body').after(spinner.spin().el);
        var users = new Users();
        var userSelect = new UserSelectList.SelectUserList();
        users.fetch({
            contentType: "application/json",
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            },

            cache: false,
            success: function (m_users) {

                userSelect.users=m_users;
             userSelect.render(UserSelectList.users);
             disposeView(new UserSelectList.SelectUserList().render());

                }

        });
```

DisposeView function

```
    function disposeView(view) {
    var current = this.currentView;
    if (current) current.close();
    current = this.currentView = view;
    current.delegateEvents();
    return current;
}
```

And i have this error [My Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRhvA.png)

How to i fix? Where is my fault?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are getting error because you have given incorrect helper name after {{/}}.

```
{{#each users}}
  <option value='{{userID}}'>{{username}}</option>
{{/users}}
```

It should be corrected to

```
{{#each users}} 
 <option value='{{userID}}'>{{username}}</option> 
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I edited this syntax error but select fill null.But console.log return my data. http://pasteboard.co/5xvUGvaor.png

Comment: You're SelectUserList view's render function needs users and you are not passing them to view during rendering and not at the time of initializing also. That's the reason you are getting anything in select.

Answer (score 0):

You have named your view `SelectUserList`. In your view you try to compile `SelectUserList` (which is your view not the template string) but you want to be passing it your template. Normally would have something like;

```
define(['text!templates/my_tempalte.hbs'],
  function(MyTemplateHbs){
    var users = new User();
    var SelectUserList = Backbone.View.extend({
      model: User,
      el:'.page',
      render:function(users)
      {
          var template = Handlebars.compile(MyTemplateHbs); //pass the tempalte
          var html = template({users:users.toJSON()});
          this.$el.html(html);
          return this;

      }
  });

  return {
      users:users,
      SelectUserList:SelectUserList
  };
)};
```

Comment: I edited this solution but now same Exception error "each doesn't match users - 3:7"

Comment: oh just seen as well the {{#each users}} needs to end {{/each}} not {{/users}}